# Mediaplayer Stop, Play, android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have two problem while running below code

1. Mediaplayer is not stopping because it's one method mp.isPlaying() always returns false.
2. Sometime i am getting invalid state exception.

```java
try {
    String[] alerts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mp3files);
    int ch;
    StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("alertNo");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
    }
    String data = new String(fileContent);
    int position = Integer.parseInt(data);
    //m.setVolume(100, 100);
    if (m.isPlaying()) {
    m.stop();
    m.release();
    }
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = 
        MySettings.this.getAssets().openFd(alerts[position] + ".mp3");
    m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), 
        descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
    descriptor.close();
    m.prepare();
    m.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) , once release is called there is no way to reuse the object. You will have to create another Mediaplayer.

Quoted.

> ```
>  after release() is called, it is in the End state
> ```

and

> Once the MediaPlayer object is in the End state, it can no longer be used and there is no way to bring it back to any other state.

So reinitialize the `m` object with a new Mediaplayer or reset it

Comment: sorry but i am always reinitialize object by MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); sorry  i forget to write but it is in before try

Comment: Not before try, You need to do it after   m.release();

Comment: Getting the same problem but I just don't release by `MediaPlayer`. It's sad the state is not a property of `MediaPlayer` but rather a value we are supposed to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by this way thanks to nandeesh :)

```
try {
                MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
                String[] alerts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mp3files);
                int ch;
                StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("alertNo");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
                }
                String data = new String(fileContent);
                int position = Integer.parseInt(data);
                //m.setVolume(100, 100);
                if (m.isPlaying()) {
                    m.stop();
                    m.release();
                    m = new MediaPlayer();
                }
                AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = MySettings.this.getAssets().openFd(alerts[position] + ".mp3");
                m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
                descriptor.close();

                m.prepare();
                m.start();
                CustomizeDialog dialog = new CustomizeDialog(MySettings.this,m);
                dialog.setTitle("Alert Test!");
                dialog.setMessage("Please Press \"Yes\" if you hear the alert sound now. if you don't here an alert, click \"No\" ");
                dialog.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```